# Encrypt HTML Source code with JAVASCRIPT. How does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encryption, cryptography

i was checking if it is possible to actually encrypt html code or not. I found a place where they encrypt the HTML code in Javascript. 
I wonder how does it work or in what format can anyone please tell me ??

Actual code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This is going to be encrypted.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The encrypted HTML CODE

```
  <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
eval(unescape('%66%75%6e%63%74%69%6f%6e%20%69%31%64%62%33%31%39%65%38%61%66%28%73%29%20%7b%0a%09%76%61%72%20%72%20%3d%20%22%22%3b%0a%09%76%61%72%20%74%6d%70%20%3d%20%73%2e%73%70%6c%69%74%28%22%37%36%39%35%39%36%38%22%29%3b%0a%09%73%20%3d%20%75%6e%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%74%6d%70%5b%30%5d%29%3b%0a%09%6b%20%3d%20%75%6e%65%73%63%61%70%65%28%74%6d%70%5b%31%5d%20%2b%20%22%38%31%33%35%32%39%22%29%3b%0a%09%66%6f%72%28%20%76%61%72%20%69%20%3d%20%30%3b%20%69%20%3c%20%73%2e%6c%65%6e%67%74%68%3b%20%69%2b%2b%29%20%7b%0a%09%09%72%20%2b%3d%20%53%74%72%69%6e%67%2e%66%72%6f%6d%43%68%61%72%43%6f%64%65%28%28%70%61%72%73%65%49%6e%74%28%6b%2e%63%68%61%72%41%74%28%69%25%6b%2e%6c%65%6e%67%74%68%29%29%5e%73%2e%63%68%61%72%43%6f%64%65%41%74%28%69%29%29%2b%2d%33%29%3b%0a%09%7d%0a%09%72%65%74%75%72%6e%20%72%3b%0a%7d%0a'));
eval(unescape('%64%6f%63%75%6d%65%6e%74%2e%77%72%69%74%65%28%69%31%64%62%33%31%39%65%38%61%66%28%27') + '%3b%21%46%51%44%56%59%5b%49%20%6e%75%79%6b%44%11%0e%3d%6a%72%78%6e%42%15%0f%36%61%77%66%7f%43%11%08%18%0c%3c%76%43%5e%6f%69%77%20%6e%77%26%62%73%6f%74%68%2a%73%77%22%66%6a%22%6d%79%67%76%79%71%7e%6c%62%30%3c%30%72%44%18%0c%3c%37%67%7b%63%79%40%13%0f%3e%37%63%76%73%6a%437695968%34%35%31%33%32%31%35' + unescape('%27%29%29%3b'));
// -->
</script>
<noscript><i>Javascript required</i></noscript>

</html>
```

You can try running in their file. It works with out any effort.So can anyone tell how did it encrypted. Or kind of encryption it is?

Comment: That looks like it's just hex encoding the characters.  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: Note that that is *encoded* not *encrypted*. Encoding isn't hard to get around

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you elaborate on why you feel the need to encode your html from your client?

Comment: Time to take a break and learn what encryption and encoding are and the difference between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as **[URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)** or percent-encoding. It's easily reversible with JavaScript's **[`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)** method, as is seen here.

The first line decrypts  to:

```
function i1db319e8af(s) {
    var r = "";
    var tmp = s.split("7695968");
    s = unescape(tmp[0]);
    k = unescape(tmp[1] + "813529");
    for( var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        r += String.fromCharCode((parseInt(k.charAt(i%k.length))^s.charCodeAt(i))+-3);
    }
    return r;
}
```

The second line is split into three parts:

```
document.write(i1db319e8af('

;!FQDVY[I nuykD=jrxnB6awfC<vC^oiw nw&bsoth*sw"fj"mygvyq~lb0<0rD<7g{cy@>7cvsjC76959684513215

'));
```

Combined as:

```
document.write(i1db319e8af(';!FQDVY[I nuykD=jrxnB6awfC<vC^oiw nw&bsoth*sw"fj"mygvyq~lb0<0rD<7g{cy@>7cvsjC76959684513215'));
```

This passes the string`;!FQDVY[I nuykD=jrxnB6awfC<vC^oiw nw&bsoth*sw"fj"mygvyq~lb0<0rD<7g{cy@>7cvsjC76959684513215` into the `i1db319e8af` function as a function parameter, and then writes the result to the page.

The `i1db319e8af` function then takes this string, and splits it into two parts on `7695968`. You then have a variable called `tmp` which contains two parts:

```
;!FQDVY[I nuykD=jrxnB6awfC<vC^oiw nw&bsoth*sw"fj"mygvyq~lb0<0rD<7g{cy@>7cvsjC
4513215
```

`k` (`4513215`) has the **string** `813529` added to it, which gets **appended**, causing the variable to be `4513215813529`.

The function then loops over the length of `;!FQDVY[I nuykD=jrxnB6awfC<vC^oiw nw&bsoth*sw"fj"mygvyq~lb0<0rD<7g{cy@>7cvsjC`, and returns what appears to be characters based on the position in characters in this string.

Note that this may return `12` characters or possibly *more*, given that it stops at the character  for me, thinking it is invalid (a character that's not `UTF-8`).

Unfortunately I don't currently have access to a sandbox, so I can't step into this further. Hopefully this will give you the info you're looking for though :)

Comment: Yes, this explain even though i still do not understand how this `;!FQDVY[I nuykD=jrxnB6awfC<vC^oiw nw&bsoth*sw"fj"mygvyq~lb0<0rD<7g{cy@>7cvsjC` junk lookiing character becoming text. And what is `4513215` and  `813529 ` these numbers. How these are generated

Comment: The string gets converted to characters with JavaScript's [**`fromCharCode()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) method. The author would have worked out what the target string was, and what the required obfsucated string would be to get it. Those two numbers are both hard-coded into the source code itself; they're not generated at all. Well, it's *possible* that they're generated dynamically with something like PHP or C# on the back-end, though that would be unlikely, and they're certainly not generated in the JavaScript :)

Answer (score 2):

Unescape operates upon hex character codes.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

```js
var myAwesomeHTMLString = "<p>Weeeee</p>";
var hexEncoded = '';

for (var i = 0; i < myAwesomeHTMLString.length; i++) {
  hexEncoded += '%'+ myAwesomeHTMLString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
}

console.log("'encoded': "+ hexEncoded);
console.log("'unencoded': "+ unescape(hexEncoded));
```

Comment: That does not encode the character.
But in that html code everything is encoded to something like ASCII or something i don't know

Comment: Hex, what you provided is hex code.  As detailed by the unescape method I linked a doc to in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This would be very weak encryption as all that is required to decrypt is readily available in the browser, namely the [unescape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
script type='application/ld+json' class='yoast-schema-graph yoast-schema-graph--main'>{"@context":"https://schema.org","@graph":[{"@type":"WebSite","@id":"https://avormin.in/#website","url":"https://avormin.in/","name":"\u0909\u0924\u094d\u092a\u093e\u0926 \u0938\u092e\u0940\u0915\u094d\u0937\u093e","potentialAction":{"@type":"SearchAction","target":"https://avormin.in/?s={search_term_string}","query-input":"required name=search_term_string"}},{"@type":"ImageObject","@id":"https://avormin.in/arthrazex#primaryimage","url":"https://avormin.in/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/1-3.jpg","width":700,"height":300},{"@type":"WebPage","@id":"https://avormin.in/arthrazex#webpage","url":"https://avormin.in/arthrazex","inLanguage":"en-US","name":"Arthrazex \u091c\u094b\u0921\u093c\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u0947 \u0932\u093f\u090f: \u0938\u0942\u091c\u0928 \u0914\u0930 \u091c\u0932\u0928 \u0926\u0942\u0930 \u0915\u0930\u0924\u0940 \u0939\u0948. \u0938\u092e\u0940\u0915\u094d\u0937\u093e, \u092e\u0942\u0932\u094d\u092f, \u092f\u0939 \u0915\u0948\u0938\u0947 \u0915\u093e\u092e \u0915\u0930\u0924\u093e \u0939\u0948, \u0930\u091a\u0928\u093e, \u0915\u0939\u093e\u0902 \u0938\u0947 \u0916\u0930\u0940\u0926\u0947\u0902.","isPartOf":{"@id":"https://avormin.in/#website"},"primaryImageOfPage":{"@id":"https://avormin.in/arthrazex#primaryimage"},"datePublished":"2020-01-31T21:00:27+03:00","dateModified":"2020-01-31T21:00:27+03:00","author":{"@id":"https://avormin.in/#/schema/person/99c8a23bb122b30eb43f5f425a89e0af"},"description":"Arthrazex \u091c\u094b\u0921\u093c\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u0947 \u0932\u093f\u090f: \u0938\u0942\u091c\u0928 \u0914\u0930 \u091c\u0932\u0928 \u0926\u0942\u0930 \u0915\u0930\u0924\u0940 \u0939\u0948. \u0938\u092e\u0940\u0915\u094d\u0937\u093e, \u092e\u0942\u0932\u094d\u092f, \u092f\u0939 \u0915\u0948\u0938\u0947 \u0915\u093e\u092e \u0915\u0930\u0924\u093e \u0939\u0948, \u0930\u091a\u0928\u093e, \u0915\u0939\u093e\u0902 \u0938\u0947 \u0916\u0930\u0940\u0926\u0947\u0902."},{"@type":["Person"],"@id":"https://avormin.in/#/schema/person/99c8a23bb122b30eb43f5f425a89e0af","name":"author2","image":{"@type":"ImageObject","@id":"https://avormin.in/#authorlogo","url":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/2696bbcbc2e8deeea6af0e36de8e159d?s=96&d=mm&r=g","caption":"author2"},"sameAs":[]}]}</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30266046)